# How to convert LinkedTreeMap Data to String data?

Tags: java

This is from openAPI for weather(openAPI = https://www.data.go.kr/)

```java
    Map<String, Object> restResult = restWeatherApi(apiMap);
```

I received a response like this from `open API`.

**Response Result**

```java
{
response=
       {header=
          {resultCode=00, resultMsg=NORMAL_SERVICE}, 
       body=
          {dataType=JSON, 
             items={item=[{baseDate=20230103, 
                    baseTime=1400, category=TMP, 
                    fcstDate=20230103, fcstTime=1500, 
                    fcstValue=0, nx=61.0, ny=127.0}, 
             {baseDate=20230103, baseTime=1400, category=UUU, f 
              cstDate=20230103, fcstTime=1500, fcstValue=2.1, 
              nx=61.0, ny=127.0}, {baseDate=20230103, 
              baseTime=1400, category=VVV, fcstDate=20230103, 
              fcstTime=1500, fcstValue=-1.2, nx=61.0, ny=127.0}, 
              {baseDate=20230103, baseTime=1400, category=VEC, 
              fcstDate=20230103, fcstTime=1500, fcstValue=300, 
              nx=61.0, ny=127.0}, {baseDate=20230103, 
              baseTime=1400, category=WSD, fcstDate=20230103, 
              fcstTime=1500, fcstValue=2.4, nx=61.0, ny=127.0}, 
              {baseDate=20230103, baseTime=1400, category=SKY, 
              fcstDate=20230103, fcstTime=1500, fcstValue=1, nx=61.0, ny=127.0}, {baseDate=20230103, baseTime=1400, category=PTY, fcstDate=20230103, fcstTime=1500, fcstValue=0, nx=61.0, ny=127.0}, {baseDate=20230103, baseTime=1400, category=POP, fcstDate=20230103, fcstTime=1500, fcstValue=0, nx=61.0, ny=127.0}, {baseDate=20230103, baseTime=1400, category=WAV, fcstDate=20230103, fcstTime=1500, fcstValue=0, nx=61.0, ny=127.0}, {baseDate=20230103, baseTime=1400, category=PCP, fcstDate=20230103, fcstTime=1500, fcstValue=강수없음, nx=61.0, ny=127.0}]}, pageNo=1.0, numOfRows=10.0, totalCount=700.0}}}
```

I wanna get data.

```
String str = restResult.get("response");
```

But Error like this.
`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

I want to use and manipulate all the data in this LinkedTreeMap.
How can I handle this data?

Comment: Your `response` property itself is a `LinkedTreeMap` see carefully. Hence you are getting this exception. You are trying to get the `response` into the `String` object. Instead using `Map<String, Object>` should fix you error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

Call `toString`.

```
restResult.get( "response" ).toString()
```

## `LinkedTreeMap` is not `String`

(Caveat: I do not use GSON.)

Your call to `restResult.get` apparently returns a reference to a `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap` object.

You assign that reference to a variable declared to hold a reference to a `String` object. A `LinkedTreeMap` object is *not* a `String` object. So your assignment attempt is incorrect, invalid.

The compiler detected your incorrect code, and flagged the error.

According to [the source code](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/LinkedTreeMap.java), that `LinkedTreeMap` class extends [`java.util.AbstractMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.html). Change your line to something like this:

```
Map map = restResult.get( "response" ) ;
```

Or:

```
var map = restResult.get( "response" ) ;
```

Then you could interrogate for key-value pairs. Or generate text representing the entire map's contents with a call to `Map#toString`. You could skip the intermediate `Map` step:

```
String str = restResult.get( "response" ).toString() ;
```